# How the result set of the following query in sql task can be assigned to a variable in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, execute-sql-task

[image: properties]

[image: configuration]

[image: variables]

Even after the below configuration , im not able to assign a query result to a variable

Comment: Read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

In the first form you have specified the `ResultSet` type as single row, and in the SQL Command you have wrote a SELECT query that may returns multiple rows.

You have to change the SQL Command, and add a `TOP 1` keyword

```
SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Also if it still not working, in the Result Set Yab, try replacing the columns names with relevant indexes.

```
MailAddressFrom >> 0
MailAddressTo >> 1
Subject >> 2
```

If you are looking to store all rows returned by a SELECT Query, you should select `FullResultSet` option and store the result inside an Object variable:

- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)